# Wordpress SSL & www rewrites

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

Having an issue with some url rewrites.
I want to redirect all urls to https with no www

Currently I have :

1) Forces https with the (s) - **working**
http://example.com => https://example.com

2) Forces https with the (s) and removes www - **working**
http://www.example.com => https://example.com

3) Remove the www from the https with the (s) requests - **failing**
https://www.example.com => https://example.com

It seems as if it's not even reaching my htaccess code with an ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT
Site might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

This is what I have in my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

The site is hosted by Host Gator and I contacted support and was told that it's impossible to set this up because the site is built with Wordpress.

That didn't seem like the right answer to me so thought I'd ask here.

Any info appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` will not detect *HTTPS* requests, so you may want to add another rule for *HTTPS* requests only (with the same/similar conditions), e.g.:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Instead of adding this, you can also simplify everything with an OR condition:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on  [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Which means, if ***HTTPS* is `null` or `off`** OR the domain does **not start with *example.com***, redirect to *https://example.com*.

Amusing that the support believes that Wordpress somehow prevents *.htaccess* to be used, but I wonder if your host may have certain *.htaccess* restrictions, preventing plugins that rely on it (e.g. BulletProof Security) to work properly.

Comment: Much appreciated for the suggestions. I've tried several variations of all of this but my SSL www requests always leads to the ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT error page. I know support @ Host Gator understands WP uses the .htaccess so it must be they have certain restrictions or I wonder if the SSL certificate itself will only work for non www variations of the name?

Comment: The error seems not to be related with the rewrite rules you are attempting but with an [issue with the certificate itself (run the scan suggested in this page, if there are no errors, it may be your browser configuration)](https://really-simple-ssl.com/knowledge-base/err_ssl_unrecognized_name_alert/)...

Comment: Much appreciated - I've been in contact with support again and now have them admitting there is an issue after attempting to create a CNAME record for the www failed. Waiting on a response from a support ticket. Will update findings here incase anyone else stumbles upon this page with the same issue.